# How to pull up to refresh the listview in android?

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I have done pulldown to refresh for my list view using by the following link https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh. But I need to pull up my list from from bottom. I searched it I got this link http://chris.banes.me/2011/12/23/pull-up-to-refresh/. But It shows some error. I don't know how to implement this. Can any body help me? Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is the error and code? We can't do much without it.

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609522/pull-to-refresh-in-android-without-popular-library/18610670#18610670

Answer (score 1):

Use [PullToRefresh](https://github.com/Maxwin-z/XListView-Android) link for pull to refresh from both(top and bottom). Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Hello asha i have also used **https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh** library and i think better to use this  library try to use 
**[https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh)** this library is easy to use and easy to integrate with your project.

I hope this will helps you.